# Why won't the compiler print new char whereas it prints new int

Tags: c++

When i enter the code:

```
    cout << new int << endl;
```

it prints out an address
but when i enter this code:

```
    cout << new char << endl;
```

it doesn't give any output, why is that?

Comment: thats how it works. There is a different `<<` overload for `int*` and for `char*`.

Comment: Often it helps to read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) of stuff that you are using